# Anyone else having issues with the 2sxc 9x build downloads being flagged as virus

Tags: 2sxc

Just trying to download the latest 2sxc 9.1.1 preview build but windows defended is flagging it at as trojan ransomware .

Westa

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else coming through this the author already submitted it to MS, I presume it is cleared by now.